# Memory issue, Not sure why. what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Im trying to write a program that outputs the next permutation of a numerical string in lexicographic order but i am getting a memory error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

I'v never had this problem before, any ideas? here is the full program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

vector<char> Next_Permutation(vector<char> InList);
void Reverse_Tail(vector<char>& List,int k);
vector<char> Swap(vector<char> InputList,int k, int l);
vector<char> GetInput();
int Find_K(vector<char> List);
int Find_l(vector<char> List,int k);
int Factorial(int n);

int main(){

 vector<char> Input = GetInput();//Getting initial input use 1234 for test

 int limit = Factorial(Input.size()); // finds how many permutations will be made

 vector<char>* AllPerms = new vector<char>[limit]; //AllPerms is the collection of all permutations(it is an array of vectors where each vector is a permutation)

 AllPerms[0] = Input; //setting intial permutation;

 for(int i=1;i<2;i++){


   // here is where i believe the program crashes. I've tried      test = Next_Permutation(AllPerms[i-1])       then 
   // doing        AllPerms[i] = Test          and the program runs through the first line fine but crashed on AllPerms[i] = Test?

  AllPerms[i] = (Next_Permutation(AllPerms[i-1]));

}
 for(int j=0; j < limit;j++){

  for(int i=0;i<AllPerms[j].size();i++){

     cout << AllPerms[j][i] << " " ;

}

cout << endl;

 }
 //cout << endl << "K = " << K << endl<< "l = " << l << endl<< endl;


  cout << endl<< endl;
  return 0;
}

int Factorial(int n){

  if(n==0)
    return 1;
  else
    return n*Factorial(n-1);

}

vector<char> Next_Permutation(vector<char> InList){

  int K = Find_K(InList);
  int l = Find_l(InList,K);

  vector<char> Output = Swap(InList,K,l);

  Reverse_Tail(Output,K);

}

void Reverse_Tail(vector<char>& List,int k){

  int i = k+1;

  int lim = (List.size() - i)/2;

  int len = List.size()-1;

  while(i < (List.size() - lim -1)){

    List = Swap(List,i,len);
    len--;
    i++;

}

}

vector<char> Swap(vector<char> InputList,int k, int l){

  vector<char> OutList = InputList;

  int Temp = OutList[l];

  OutList[l] = InputList[k];

  OutList[k] = Temp;

  return OutList;

}

int Find_l(vector<char> List,int k){

  int l=List.size()-1;

  while(List[l] < List[k]){

    l--;

  }

  return l;

}

int Find_K(vector<char> List){

  int k = List.size()-2;

  while(List[k] > List[k+1]){

    k--;

  }

  if(k == List.size()-1){

    return -1;

  }

  return k;

}

vector<char> GetInput(){

vector<char> InputString;

cout << "Please input the string of symbols you would like to gain all permutations of: ";

char temp = 0 ;

while( temp != '\n' ){

cin.get(temp);

InputString.push_back(temp);

}

InputString.pop_back();

return  InputString;

}
```

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` is thrown when new fails.  I would look to see what `limit` is set to.  Using the factorial as an array limit can very VERY quickly run out of memory.

Comment: 1. Fix code indentation. 2. Attach a debugger and see where the exception originates.

Comment: I would replace `vector<char>*` with vector<vector<char>> for clarity, took me a moment to realize that wasn't a typo/bug.

Comment: How big is your input string when it crashes?

Comment: this looks like a simple debug session activity would solve it. have you tried it yourself before submitting to the SO "human compilers"?

Comment: yea i tried to debug but it always just crashed at  AllPerms[i] = (Next_Permutation(AllPerms[i-1]));
and when i tested the program i was using the string 1234

Comment: I have also tried doing a vector< vector<char> > AllPerms; and storing the new vector in that using AllPerms.push_back(Next_Permutation(AllPerms[i-1])) and i got the same memory error?

Comment: http://codepad.org/gK5Sbp3l  This server runs the (modified) program without error, for whatever it's worth.  I see nothing in the code that should be problematic.

Comment: what do you mean by "modified?"

Comment: The server probably has more memory. "It crashes" means *start debugging* not *stop and ask SO*

Comment: Cdd, @Mooing Duck added `return Output` to the end of `Next_Permutation` and also modified `GetInput` so it would use hard-coded input instead of prompting for something from the keyboard (which isn't supported on Codepad). When I make that same change to `Next_Permutation`, the program runs without crashing for me, too. It doesn't produce correct output, but that's not the issue you're worried about yet.

Comment: ok thanks, can believe i missed that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't return a value from `Next_Permutation`. Failure to return a value from any function but `main` invokes *undefined behavior*, where the compiler and the program are free to do anything they like. My Solaris compiler refuses to accept the program, whereas my Linux compiler compiles the program, but then the program crashes because `free` detected an invalid pointer at some point. Both are valid ways to treat something that's undefined.

When you have undefined behavior, it's generally not wise to put much effort into figuring out exactly why your program is behaving strangely because whatever you're seeing isn't necessarily reproducible by anyone else, and possibly not even reproducible by *you*. Make sure you have a valid program, and *then* start debugging. Although it's possible that you're legitimately running out of memory, it's more likely that the exception is being thrown while trying to copy something that's not even a valid object in the first place.

Your compiler probably offers some diagnostics, but you might have to request them when you run it. If you're using g++, make sure to include the `-Wall` option, which enables "all" warnings. (There are a few obscure ones that aren't enabled, but you generally don't need to worry about them.)